# how to detect door in floor plan image file using emgu.cv in C#

Tags: c#, image, image-processing, geojson, emgucv

**What i have tried ?**

I have image file and geojson file, i need to overlay the geojson file on the image and do some color changes in the room and door.

i have used the emgu.cv library to detect the room and able to switch the color in the image.

**Got stuck here**

but i need find the room door as well and change the color.. but i have only coordinates for the room. how can i able to find the room door in this ?

Do i need the room door coordinates as well ?
I have tried to detect the room door by using the room color(yellow), but it detects both the door in the room.

need some guidance on how to approach this please.

```
 static void DetectAndDrawDoors(Image<Bgr, byte> image, List<PolygonData> polygonDataList)
 {
     Mat hsvImage = new Mat();
     CvInvoke.CvtColor(image, hsvImage, ColorConversion.Bgr2Hsv);


     ScalarArray lowerBound = new ScalarArray(new MCvScalar(20, 50, 0));
     ScalarArray upperBound = new ScalarArray(new MCvScalar(29, 255, 100));

     Mat yellowMask = new Mat();
     CvInvoke.InRange(hsvImage, lowerBound, upperBound, yellowMask);

     CvInvoke.GaussianBlur(yellowMask, yellowMask, new Size(5, 5), 0);

     CvInvoke.MorphologyEx(yellowMask, yellowMask, MorphOp.Open, CvInvoke.GetStructuringElement(ElementShape.Rectangle, new Size(5, 5), new Point(-1, -1)), new Point(-1, -1), 1, BorderType.Default, new MCvScalar());

     VectorOfVectorOfPoint contours = new VectorOfVectorOfPoint();
     CvInvoke.FindContours(yellowMask, contours, null, RetrType.List, ChainApproxMethod.ChainApproxSimple);


     // Iterate over contours using a for loop
     for (int i = 0; i < contours.Size; i++)
     {
         VectorOfPoint approxContour = new VectorOfPoint();
         CvInvoke.ApproxPolyDP(contours[i], approxContour, 10, false);

         if (CvInvoke.ContourArea(approxContour) > 20)
         {
             Rectangle boundingBox = CvInvoke.BoundingRectangle(approxContour);

             // Check if the current contour is part of any active polygon
             foreach (var polygonData in polygonDataList.Where(pd => pd.Active == "True"))
             {
                 if (IsContourInActivePolygon(approxContour, polygonData.Coordinates))
                 {
                     CvInvoke.Rectangle(image, boundingBox, new MCvScalar(0, 255, 0), 20);

                 }

             }
         }
     }

 }

 static bool IsContourInActivePolygon(VectorOfPoint contour, List<Coordinate> polygonCoordinates)
 {
     // Convert contour points to coordinates
     List<Coordinate> contourCoordinates = contour.ToArray().Select(point => new Coordinate { Latitude = point.Y, Longitude = point.X }).ToList();

     // Check if any point of the contour is inside the polygon
     return contourCoordinates.Any(point => IsPointInPolygon(point, polygonCoordinates));
 }

 static bool IsPointInPolygon(Coordinate point, List<Coordinate> polygonCoordinates)
 {
     // Implementation of point in polygon algorithm
     int count = polygonCoordinates.Count;
     bool inside = false;

     for (int i = 0, j = count - 1; i < count; j = i++)
     {
         if (((polygonCoordinates[i].Latitude > point.Latitude) != (polygonCoordinates[j].Latitude > point.Latitude)) &&
             (point.Longitude < (polygonCoordinates[j].Longitude - polygonCoordinates[i].Longitude) * (point.Latitude - polygonCoordinates[i].Latitude) / (polygonCoordinates[j].Latitude - polygonCoordinates[i].Latitude) + polygonCoordinates[i].Longitude))
         {
             inside = !inside;
         }
     }

     return inside;
 }
```

Image reference for what i achieved :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDoBz.png)

Sample geojson value for room 34

```
   {
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
            [
                768,
                74
            ],
            [
                768,
                322
            ],
            [
                851,
                322
            ],
            [
                875,
                346
            ],
            [
                872,
                349
            ],
            [
                872,
                350
            ],
            [
                931,
                409
            ],
            [
                934,
                406
            ],
            [
                935,
                406
            ],
            [
                959,
                430
            ],
            [
                959,
                522
            ],
            [
                1102,
                522
            ],
            [
                1102,
                74
            ]
        ]
    },
    "properties": {
        "active": true,
        "roomname": "34",
        "disp_label": "",
        "arch_ref": ""
    }
},
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? If the idea is to use actual image analysis to find features in the image you probably need at least some prior knowledge on the subject. This may be a fairly complex task, and SO is not a free code writing service.

Comment: Apologies! I'm new to this subject.. but i managed to find these to proceed and stuck on this final bit..  I have updated my question with what i tried as well.  @JonasH

Comment: Your edits make your question much better, but it is still not clear to me what your actual, specific,  goal is. You might want to post the input image as well as an example of your desired output. You might also want to convert your polygon to a pixel representation and post that as well. EmguCV probably has some draw methods, but there are also the builtin `Graphics.FromImage` that could be used. Finally if there are multiple doors, and you only want one of them, you need *some* method to select one or the other, having explicit door coordinates would do it, but there might be other ways.